# Why does the human blood look colorless in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, transformers, bumblebee

In *Bumblebee* (2018), one of the Decepticons shot the human with their gun, causing the human to explode into what looked like colorless blood:

[image: guy exploding]

Why does the human blood look colorless?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because this film has a lower age rating than the previous Transformers films, entitling young children to see it.

The MPAA rated this film as

> PG-13 for sequences of sci-fi action violence

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Association_of_America_film_rating_system#Violence):

> Depictions of violence are permitted under all ratings but must be moderated for the lower ones. Violence must be kept to a minimum in G rated films and must not be intense in PG rated films. Depictions of intense violence are permitted under the PG-13 rating, but violence that is both realistic and extreme or persistent will generally require at least an R rating.

So, using "sci-fi" weapons to reduce someone to a harmless looking gloop allows the film to retain the intended PG13 rating.

Comment: Minor point: All other live-action Transformers films have also been MPAA rating PG-13